# Custom validations does not work in kendo ui grid update

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

here is my code......
In here I try to add custom validation to update.

```
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: {
                                            validation: {
                                                required: true,
                                                productnamevalidation: function (input) {
                                                    if (input.is("[name='ProductName']") && input.val() != "") {
                                                        input.attr("data-productnamevalidation-msg", "Product Name should start with capital letter");
                                                        return /^[A-Z]/.test(input.val());
                                                    }

                                                    return true;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { unitValidations :                                                                  function(input){
                                                                if ((input.val() <= 1000) && (input.val() >= 10)) {
                        input.attr("data-max-msg","value must in given range");
                        input.attr("data-min-msg","value must in given range");
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    } }, required: true} }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 550,
                        toolbar: ["create"],
                        columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "120px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "120px" },
                            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px"}],
                        editable: "inline"
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
```

In here you can see I added custom validation for update field....

```
   UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { unitValidations :                                                               function(input){
                                                                    if ((input.val() <= 1000) && (input.val() >= 10)) {
                            input.attr("data-max-msg","value must in given range");
                            input.attr("data-min-msg","value must in given range");
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        } }, required: true} }
```

But it is not working fine. What should I change ??
you can run this from [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/)

Comment: Your *dojo link is pointing to the root site, do you meant to point to code ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - really sorry about that...
Here is the [link] (http://dojo.telerik.com/eBITi) ....
I think now this will work